# Ring isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ring-isomorphism

I am trying to prove the following:

If there exists a ring isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}(i)$, then there exists a ring isomorphism $g:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that $g(\sqrt{2})=i$.

My approach to the problem was trying to find a ring isomorphism $h:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ such that $h(\sqrt{2})=a$, where $a\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is such that $f(a)=i$. Then I would define $g=f\circ h$. However, I have not been able to find a ring isomorphism $h$ that works.

It would be very helpful if anyone could suggest either a different approach to tackle the problem or maybe the ring isomorphism $h$ I was looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The implication is true because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ isn’t isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, since $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ contains no solution to the equation $x^2=1+1$.

Comment: A bit more obvious to say that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ doesn't contain a root of $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is no ring isomorphism $f : \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}) \to \Bbb Q(i)$.
Indeed, if $f$ were such an isomorphism, then $f$ would have to map $1$ to $1$ and by extension, $f(n) = n$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z$.

Now, note that $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2$. Applying $f$ on both sides and using the fact that it is a homomorphism along with the above observation gives $$f(\sqrt{2})^2 = 2.$$
However, $f(\sqrt{2}) \in \Bbb Q(i)$ but there is no element in $\Bbb Q(i)$ whose square is $2$.

---

Thus, the given statement is true vacuously.